# Merge/concat values of an attribute in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, concatenation

im stuck at this point:

**XML source**

```
<config>
  <username>user</username>
  <password>pass</password>
  <link>1.2.3.4</link>
  <port>99</port>
</config>
```

**XML target**

```
<some wrapping="tag"> <!-- is fixed and should be just inserted -->
  <property name="username" value="user"/>
  <property name="password" value="pass"/>
  <!-- link and port are merged into one attribute -->
  <property name="URL" value="1.2.3.4:99" />
</some>
```

**XSLT i have so far**

```
<xsl:template match="config">
  <some wrapping="tag">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </some>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config/username | config/password">
  <property name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </property>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It gives me desired result until it comes to the point of merging **link** and **port** nodes into **URL** property with value of port and link.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/config">
    <some wrapping="tag">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="username | password"/>
        <property name="URL" value="{concat(link, ':', port)}" />
    </some>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <property name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </property>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/config">
    <some wrapping="tag">
        <xsl:for-each select="username | password">
            <property name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </property>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <property name="URL" value="{concat(link, ':', port)}" />
    </some>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a transparent and easy to read solution, just code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="config">
    <some wrapping="tag">
      <property name="username" value="{username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="{password}"/>
      <!-- link and port are merged into one attribute -->
      <property name="URL" value="{link}:{port}" />
    </some>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea. But of course the identity transform template is completely redundant and does not serve your goal of  "a transparent and easy to read solution".

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I totally agree with you. I was supposing the PO had other parts of his source he wanted to preserve. If this is not the case, we can remove the identity transformation which is redundant in this minimal example. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Even shorter**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="10">
    <some wrapping="tag">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </some>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::port)]">
    <property name="{concat(substring(name(), string-length(name())*(name()='link') +1),
                            substring('URL', 3*(not(name()='link')) +1))}"           
        value="{concat(.,substring(concat(':',../port), 
                                   (string-length(../port)+1)*not(name()='link')+1) )}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**:

1. The `<property>` element is constructed only in a single place in the code, regardless of the name of the element that is matched by the template.
2. The code is generic and doesn't mention explicitly element names such as "`username`" or "`password`"